# Is it possible to use an EMC SAN in iscsi without starting any Powerwhatever dæmon?

Tags: linux, iscsi, emc

I can't seem to get my iscsi targets working without starting the PowerPath module, even though I don't actually use it.

Is it at all possible?

Edit: Precision, I'm not currently even using multipathing. But if I don't start /etc/init.d/PowerPath, accessing the devices fail with I/O error. When I start this non-LSB compliant script, it then begins to work.

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

yes, device-mapper-multipath and open-iscsi can work without powerpath.

read the dm-mp manpages and the guides for using iscsi initiator (man iscsiadm)